# VLOOKUP and INDEX return #N/A when referencing another LOOKUP cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010, lookup

I'm working on an Excel 2010 worksheet that uses a table that references a secondary table to generate a list of values.

More specifically, I have two tables: `Table_Players` and `Table_ChallengeCalc`. In `Table_Players`, I have the columns `Players`, `Experience`, and `Level`. I input the total number of points that a given player has under the experience table, and using this formula the level column tells me what level the player is:

Table_Players: 
[image: Table_Players]

> =LOOKUP(C6,
>   {-1;0;300;900;2700;6500;14000;23000;34000;48000;64000;85000;100000;120000;140000;165000;195000;225000;265000;305000;355000},{"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"10";"11";"12";"13";"14";"15";"16";"17";"18";"19";"20"})

`Table_ChallengeCalc` resides on a different sheet in the workbook, and references the `Level` value in `Table_Players` to pull a list of additional values from another table, `Table_Difficulty`.

Before I implemented the above `lookup` formula, I was just manually inputting the player's levels and in turn, the `Table_ChallengeCalc` was pulling the correct values for the remaining columns, using this to load the player's assigned level on `Table_Players`:

Table_ChallengeCalc:
[image: Table_ChallengeCalc]

> =VLOOKUP([Players],Table_Players[Level],3,FALSE)

(Here's what it looks like when it works correctly): 
[image]

However, as soon as I added the first `LOOKUP` value, the second `VLOOKUP` immediately became `#N/A` and in turn, so did all of the rest of the reference columns. If I remove the first `lookup` and manually enter the level again, the `VLOOKUP` immediately starts working again. I tried using a nested `INDEX`/`MATCH` statement, but it had the same results. As long as I'm using that first `LOOKUP`, `Table_ChallengeCalc` can't seem to pull the level value.

If I didn't know any better, it would seem to me that the workbook is trying to run the `VLOOKUP` simultaneously, if not immediately prior, the `LOOKUP` formula. Any ideas on how I can counter this, or is this one of those things where I've kind of hit the limitations of what an Excel workbook can do without additional software like `VBA`?

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow, especially when it comes down to which table is which. For example, I am not sure which table is `Table_PlayerListing` and which is `Table_Players`.

Comment: My apologies - there is no Table_PlayerListing, it's just Table_Players. Edited in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, then using the following formula should work for you:

```
=VLOOKUP([Players], Table_Players, 3, FALSE)
```

You currently have this in your **table_array**: `Table_Players[Level]`, but your "[Level]" column is coming from the **col_index_num**: `3` in the formula, so you should not include this in your table array.